Why is custom pytree 'aux_data' traced after jax.jit() for jnp.array but not for np.array?
I am trying to understand how pytrees work and registered my own class as a pytree. I noticed that if the aux_data in the pytree is a jax.numpy.ndarray the auxilliary data is subsequently traced and returned as a Traced<ShapedArray(...)>.... However, if the aux_data is a numpy.ndarray (i.e. not JAX array), then it is not traced and returns an array from a jit tranformed function.
Now, I am aware of the tracing that happens during the jax.jit() transformation, but I do not understand why, on the level of pytrees, this results in the behaviour described above.
Here is an example to reproduce this behaviour (multiplying both the aux_data and the tree leaves by two, which may be a problem in itself after JIT transformation...?). I have used the custom pytree implementations of accepted libraries (equinox and simple_pytree) for comparison, and they all give the same result, so that I am very sure that this is not a bug but a feature that I am trying to understand.
import jax
from jax.tree_util import tree_structure, tree_leaves
import numpy as np

def get_pytree_impl(base):
    if base == "equinox":
        import equinox as eqx
        Module = eqx.Module
        static_field = eqx.static_field
    elif base == "simple_pytree":
        from simple_pytree import Pytree, static_field
        Module = Pytree
    elif base == "dataclasses":
        from dataclasses import dataclass, field
        @dataclass
        class Module():
            pass
        static_field = field
    
    class PytreeImpl(Module):
        x: jax.numpy.ndarray
        y: jax.numpy.ndarray = static_field()

        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    if base == 'dataclasses':
        from jax.tree_util import register_pytree_node
        
        def flatten(ptree):
            return ((ptree.x,), ptree.y)
        
        def unflatten(aux_data, children):
            return PytreeImpl(*children, aux_data)

        register_pytree_node(PytreeImpl, flatten, unflatten)
        
    return PytreeImpl

def times_two(ptree):
    return type(ptree)(ptree.x*2, ptree.y*2)

times_two_jitted = jax.jit(times_two)

bases = ['dataclasses', 'equinox', 'simple_pytree']
for base in bases:
    print("========  " + base + "  ========")
    for lib_name, array_lib in zip(['jnp', 'np'], [jax.numpy, np]):
        print("====  " + lib_name)
        PytreeImpl = get_pytree_impl(base)
        x = jax.numpy.array([1,2])
        y = array_lib.array([3,4])
        input_tree = PytreeImpl(x, y)
        for tag, pytree in zip(["input", "no_jit", "jit"],[input_tree, times_two(input_tree), times_two_jitted(input_tree)]):
            print(f' {tag}:')
            print(f'\t Structure: {tree_structure(pytree)}')
            print(f'\t Leaves: {tree_leaves(pytree)}')

This produces the follwing, where dataclasses is my naive custom implementation of a pytree:
========  dataclasses  ========
====  jnp
 input:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[[3 4]], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]
 no_jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[[6 8]], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
 jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[Traced<ShapedArray(int32[2])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
====  np
 input:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[[3 4]], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]
 no_jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[[6 8]], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
 jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[[6 8]], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
========  equinox  ========
====  jnp
 input:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[('x',), ('y',), (Array([3, 4], dtype=int32),)], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]
 no_jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[('x',), ('y',), (Array([6, 8], dtype=int32),)], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
 jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[('x',), ('y',), (Traced<ShapedArray(int32[2])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>,)], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
====  np
 input:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[('x',), ('y',), (array([3, 4]),)], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]
 no_jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[('x',), ('y',), (array([6, 8]),)], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
 jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[('x',), ('y',), (array([6, 8]),)], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
========  simple_pytree  ========
====  jnp
 input:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[(('x',), {'y': Array([3, 4], dtype=int32), '_pytree__initialized': True})], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]
 no_jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[(('x',), {'y': Array([6, 8], dtype=int32), '_pytree__initialized': True})], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
 jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[(('x',), {'y': Traced<ShapedArray(int32[2])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, '_pytree__initialized': True})], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
====  np
 input:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[(('x',), {'y': array([3, 4]), '_pytree__initialized': True})], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]
 no_jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[(('x',), {'y': array([6, 8]), '_pytree__initialized': True})], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]
 jit:
     Structure: PyTreeDef(CustomNode(PytreeImpl[(('x',), {'y': array([6, 8]), '_pytree__initialized': True})], [*]))
     Leaves: [Array([2, 4], dtype=int32)]

I ran this example using Python 3.12.1 with
equinox           0.11.4
jax               0.4.28
jaxlib            0.4.28
simple-pytree     0.1.5

From the JAX docs:

When defining unflattening functions, in general children should contain all the dynamic elements of the data structure (arrays, dynamic scalars, and pytrees), while aux_data should contain all the static elements that will be rolled into the treedef structure.

aux_data in a pytree flattening must contain static elements, and static elements must be hashable and immutable. Neither np.ndarray nor jax.Array satisfy this, so they should not be included in aux_data. If you do include such values in aux_data, you'll get unsupported, poorly-defined behavior.
With that background: the answer to your question of why you're seeing the results you're seeing is that you are defining your pytrees incorrectly. If you define aux_data to only contain static (i.e. hashable and immutable) attributes, you will no longer see this behavior.

Thanks for the clear answer! Is this requirement documented somewhere? The only place I could find in the documentation that vaguely hints at what you say would be in a code example (https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working-with-pytrees.html#pytrees-custom-pytree-nodes) where the docstring of the "special_flatten" function says "The auxiliary data could be used, for example, for dictionary keys" but this is not very clearly saying that the aux_data must be hashable and immutable.

Thanks, I see this in your edit now. It is saying "JAX sometimes needs to compare treedef for equality, or compute its hash for use in the JIT cache, and so care must be taken to ensure that the auxiliary data specified in the flattening recipe supports meaningful hashing and equality comparisons." which I must have missed.
